# unir dos listas de tipo List en Java

Tags: java, array, lista

Quiero aprender a unir dos listas, objetos de tipo List, para generar una tercera lista a partir de las anteriores. No se como hacerlo de forma mas directa. He desarrollado un metodo que funciona y que muestro a continuación para que se entienda lo que pretendo, pero creo que se puede hacer de forma mas directa usando correctamente los metodos add o addAll propios de List, pero no lo consigo.
En mi metodo primero paso los objetos List a array, luego concateno los array el array resultanto lo paso a List usando Arrays.asList(array3).

```
private static List<Character> concatenarList(List<Character> listA, List<Character> listB ) {

        Character[] array1 = new Character [listA.size()]; 
        Character[] array2 = new Character [listB.size()];
        listA.toArray(array1);//paso el objeto List list1 al array1 
        listB.toArray(array2);//paso el objeto list2 al array2 
        
        
        Character[] array3 = new Character[array1.length + array2.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            array3[i] = array1[i];
        }
        int b = array1.length ;
        for (int a = 0; a < array2.length; a++) {            
            array3[b] = array2[a];
            b++;            
        }
        
        List<Character> list3 = Arrays.asList(array3);
        return list3;
    }
```

Comment: Solamente usa el método [List.addAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#addAll(int,java.util.Collection))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el método [List.addAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#addAll(int,java.util.Collection)) para concatenar dos listas del mismo objeto.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Character> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList('1', '2', '3'));
        ArrayList<Character> list2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList('4', '5', '6'));
        list1.addAll(list2);

        System.out.println(list1);
    }
}
```

**output**

```
// Lista 1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```